# Dynamic click event issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom, button

I have a table being loaded from a JSON array, but my click event solution does not seem to work. As the loop is cycled through, I add a click event to each listener to each of the new added divs.

```
document.getElementById(i.toString()).addEventListener("click", function(event)
{
    console.log(event);
});
```

The issue is only the last element responds to the clicks.

My code is available on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mkgYJxZZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the way you are currently trying to add new elements to your html.

Replace this (what you are currently doing):

```
nw.innerHTML = nw.innerHTML + "<div class='" + nodeType + "' id='" + i + "'><div class='nodeName'>" + json[i][0] + "</div></div>";
```

With this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("class", nodeType);
div.setAttribute("id", i.toString());
div.innerHTML = '<div class="nodeName">' + json[i][0] + '</div>';
nw.appendChild(div);
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wggcm1ty/) that shows a simpler version of this working.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,

```
nw.innerHTML = nw.innerHTML + "<div class='" + nodeType + "' id='" + i + "'><div class='nodeName'>" + json[i][0] + "</div></div>";
```

this code override previous nw's elements and their event listeners too.

Therefore, instead of using innerHTML, try to use `document.createElement("div")` and append it to `nw` using `appendChild()`. It works in my test.